# Compute the Lie derivative for $X=y \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and $Y=x \frac{\partial}{\partial y}$

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-derivative

> **Question**: On $\mathbf{R}^2$, let $X=y \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and let $Y=x \frac{\partial}{\partial y}$, with corresponding flows given by $\phi_t(x, y)=(x+t y, y)$ and $\psi_t(x, y)=(x, y+t x)$. Then show that the Lie derivative, $\mathcal L_XY=-x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$

The definition given in the book,

> Definition 4.7.1. Let $T$ be a tensor field of type $(r, s)$ on $\mathbf{R}^n$ and let $X$ be a vector field with flow $\phi_t: \mathbf{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbf{R}^n$. The Lie derivative of $T$ with respect to $X$, denoted by $\mathcal{L}_X T$, is the $(r, s)$-tensor defined as
> $$
> \mathcal{L}_X T=\left.\frac{d}{d t}\right|_{t=0}\left(\phi_t^* T\right) .
> $$

But when we have a ambient space like for this example then do we need the flow to define the Lie derivative? Inspired from this [M.SE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2736629/736159), I give a try below:
$$
\begin{align}
\mathcal L_XY&=\mathcal L_X\left(x\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)\\
&=[\mathcal L_X(x)]\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+x[\mathcal L_X\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)]\\
&=[y\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x)]\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+x[y\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)]\\
&=y\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+?
\end{align}
$$

but here I guess $\mathcal L_X(\frac{\partial}{\partial y})$ doesn't make sense! Or I am not expert enough to guess the meaning.

Comment: Apply the definition you just put up there!

Comment: Okay, the book doesn't show any computation for pullback explicitly. here is mentioned two flow, then which flow I should pick? Like for $\phi_t^*\left(x\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)$ But isn't pullback only defined on forms? Here it is a vector field @TedShifrin

Comment: Right. The notation is explained in the book. For a contravariant tensor, you push forward by the flow.

Comment: You should explicitly mention which book you are referring to. "The book" is a bit vague

Comment: There is a typo in your expression for $L_XY$: it should end with $y\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$, note $x\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$.

Comment: Thank you @Didier fixed the typo. Can you help me with [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4858603/736159) related with covariant derivative. Actually, I was looking for resource where things are explained with example. but couldn't manage. Let me know if you have one where connections, curvature, bundles are explained with example. Thanks again.

Comment: [This book by R.W.R. Darling](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/differential-forms-and-connections/767FC792F030D351AF5E65D0434248F5) may be helpful to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the definition that you are given.
The flow of $X$ is $\phi_t(x,y) = (x+ty,y)$.
The Lie derivative $\mathcal{L}_XY$ is given by
$$
L_XY = \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0} (\phi_t)^*Y,
$$
and for $p\in \Bbb R^2$, the pullback $(\phi_t)^*Y$ at $p$ is given by
$$
((\phi_t)^*Y)_p = {(d\phi_t)_p}^{-1} \left(Y_{\phi_t(p)}\right).
$$
Let us proceed step by step.
Fix $t,x$ and $y$.
Then $\phi_t(x,y) = (x+ty,y)$.
Hence, $Y_{\phi_t(x,y)} = (x+ty)\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$.
Now, $d\phi_t(x,y)$ is the linear isomorphism whose matrix in the basis $\{\frac{\partial}{\partial x},\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\}$ is given by
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & t \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix},
$$
and it follows that its inverse ${(d\phi_t)_{(x,y)}}^{-1}$ is the linear isomorphism whose matrix in the same basis is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -t \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Hence, we have
$$
((\phi_t)^*Y)_{(x,y)}
= (x+ty)\left(-t\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \right)
= -tx\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + ty\frac{\partial}{\partial y} -t^2y \frac{\partial}{\partial y}.
$$
Its derivative with respect to $t$ is
$$
\frac{d}{dt} ((\phi_t)^*Y)_{(x,y)}
= -x \frac{\partial}{\partial x} +y\frac{\partial}{\partial y} -2ty\frac{\partial}{\partial x}.
$$
Evaluating at $t=0$ gives
$$
(\mathcal{L}_XY)_{(x,y)}
= -x\frac{\partial}{\partial x} +y\frac{\partial}{\partial y},
$$
which is the desired result.

As an instructive exercise, you can mimic this proof to compute $\mathcal{L}_YX$.
You should find the opposite of the above result.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detail answer.  One last confusion, why the inverse ${(d\phi_t)_p}^{-1}$ in the $((\phi_t)^*Y)_p = {(d\phi_t)_p}^{-1} \left(Y_{\phi_t(p)}\right)$. I ask this because isn't it the inverse of the Jacobian? I guess it by jacobian only but the inverse thing make me confused, @Didier

Comment: @falamiw This is the definition of the pullback of a vector field by a diffeomorphism, that's it. More conceptually, you are pulling a vector that is tangent at the point $\phi_t(x,y)$ back at the original point $(x,y)$. The linear map $(d\phi_t)_{(x,y)}$ sends vectors tangent at $(x,y)$ to vectors tangent at $\phi_t(x,y)$, so it is not the right linear map to use. Meanwhile, its inverse goes in the reverse direction, which is what you are looking for.
This may seems arbitrary on $\Bbb R^2$, but once you will work on abstract manifolds, you'll see that it's the only thing that makes sense.